# Como pular de uma aba para a outra no Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text

Existe algum atalho no teclado para pular de uma aba a outra no Sublime Text?

Comment: `alt + 1`, `alt + 2`, `alt + 3`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe a [documentação](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html#tabs) **não oficial** que informa:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: Abre a última guia fechada;

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>: Move para a guia acima;

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>: Move para a guia abaixo;

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>: Fecha a guia atual;

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[NUM]</kbd>: Move para a guia `[NUM]`, sendo `[NUM]` menor ou igual ao número de guias abertas;

Você pode confirmar as informações acima acessando, no seu editor: *Preferences / Key Bindings*. Busque pelas informações `next_view` e `prev_view`.

No meu caso, há a seguinte configuração:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+pagedown"], "command": "next_view" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+pageup"], "command": "prev_view" },
```

O atalho para selecionar uma guia específica é encontrada por `select_by_index`.

No meu caso:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+1"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 0 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+2"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 1 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+3"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 2 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+4"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 3 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+5"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 4 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+6"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 5 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+7"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 6 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+8"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 7 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+9"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 8 } },
{ "keys": ["alt+0"], "command": "select_by_index", "args": { "index": 9 } },
```

Answer (score 9):

Em Windows/Linux (PC) o como o Renan respondeu:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> Vai para aba anterior
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> Vai para próxima aba

Em Mac OSX:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> Vai para aba a esquerda
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> Vai para aba a direita

### Outros atalhos

- Em PC <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[NUM]</kbd> Navega entre abas pela ordem que estão posicionadas, por exemplo <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> irá para a nona aba, se ela existir
- Em Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[NUM]</kbd> Navega entre abas pela ordem que estão posicionadas

> No SublimeText3 estes atalhos são padrões, não sei se difere alguma coisa do 2

### Mais atalhos em:

> Não é a documentação oficial

- [Atalhos para Mac](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html)
- [Atalhos para PC](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html)

Answer (score 6):

[RTFM](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html#tabs)

**TL;DR:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> e <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> navegam entre abas, para a frente e para atrás respectivamente.

Comment: No meu o PU vai para trás e o PD vai para a frente, confere?

Comment: @Math acho que é uma questão de perspectiva.